# Java doubt on unique date issue

Tags: java

In a loop, I am to create a new object only if the date is different than the previously iterated value. Otherwise i want the same object. Can anyone help?

Comment: Only if the date is different to what? Your question is very unclear. Sample code would help, indicating where you're stuck.

Comment: "only if the date is different" from which date ?

Comment: composition + immutable common object (shared)

Comment: Sample code showing what you're trying to do would still help clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions lacks a lot of information so I can't give you code you can use with out changes. Here is the general code that you seem to be asking for. You will need to fill in the comments with code that matches what you were asking for.

```
curDate = null;
lastDate = null;
for(/*loop statement*/){
    lastDate = curDate;
    curDate = /*get next date from iterator*/;
    if(lastDate == null){
        continue;
    }
    if(lastDate.compareTo(curDate) == 0){
        /*the same object*/
    }else{
        /*create a new object*/
    }
}
```